# Memory Management When Navigating Between View Without Using Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been working on iOS application in swift from last 40-45 days. It has around 20 screens. I have implemented google map, payment gateway and many other UI component into it.

My problem is it is showing memory usage around 120 MB in flows which is very high for mobile devices. I did not used navigation controller and I have created all UI component programmatically.

In order to move from one view to another view, I have connected them via segue and in prepare for segue method I am sending data if needed. Given code is moving from one view to another

```
@IBAction func goToSearchFromHome(searchButton: UIButton) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("homeToSearchSegue", sender: self)

}
```

In order to come on previous page I am using following code:

```
@IBAction func goToHomePage(homeButton: UIButton) {

    let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeScreen")


    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Ideally, when moving from one screen to another, memory usage should include on that instance of view. What should I do in order to solve my problem?

Comment: Map is taking more memory then any other control. So it is normal for device. Maximum 160 mb memory load is make your application work without any issue on iphone 4s so It will be more smooth on other devices where device configuration is high. So When u navigating, In viewwilldisappear  Make your map = nil and delegate = nil; So that is can release map and memory too. When u comeback to this view again write your code of map in viewwillappear method. hope this will work for you

Comment: @Jecky Don't answer questions in comments. Just post an answer.